Kubernetes: Influxdb 1.8.10 container can’t create users
I deployed on docker InfluxDB v 1.8.10 with command:
docker run --name influxdb -t
-e INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=“true”
-e INFLUXDB_DB=“mydatabase”
-e INFLUXDB_USER=“user”
-e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=“user”
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=“admin”
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=“admin”
–restart unless-stopped
-d influxdb:1.8.10

When I connect I see that the new Admin user is created.
Now I would like to deploy it on Kubernetes, this is my code:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
    name: influxdb
    namespace: mon-grafana
spec:
  serviceName: influxdb
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: influxdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: influxdb:1.8.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
          name: influxdb
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 500Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 500Mi
        env:
        - name: INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: INFLUXDB_DB
          value: "mydatabase"
        - name: INFLUXDB_USER
          value: "user"
        - name: INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD
          value: "user"
        - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc-influxdb
          mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
        - name: influxdb-config
          mountPath: "/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf"
          subPath: influxdb.conf
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      volumes:
      - name: influxdb-config
        configMap:
          name: configmap
          items:
          - key: influxdb.conf
            path: influxdb.conf
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvc-influxdb
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi

this is my infliuxdb.conf file:
root@influxdb-0:/# cat /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
reporting-enabled = false

[meta]
dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/meta”

[data]
dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/data”
wal-dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/wal”
max-series-per-database = 1000000
max-values-per-tag = 100000
index-version = “tsi1”
max-index-log-file-size = “100k”

[http]
log-enabled = false
enabled = true
bind-address = “0.0.0.0:8086”
https-enabled = false
flux-enabled = true

but the Admin user is not created, and when I try to connect I receive this error:

root@influxdb-0:/# influx -username admin -password admin Connected to
http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.10 InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.10
show databases; ERR: error authorizing query: create admin user first
or disable authentication Warning: It is possible this error is due to
not setting a database. Please set a database with the command “use ”.

